# Converter NVARCHAR para NUMERICO

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Tenho uma tabela que possui uma coluna VALOR, mas a coluna está em nvarchar, essa coluna nvarchar não deixa eu fazer a formatação correta no relatório em que estou usando o select.

Consigo fazer a conversão no SQL Server para o tipo money, mas não fica no padrão correto. Dentro do Visual Studio usei conversores que também não funcionam corretamente.

Exemplo, na tabela se tem o valor 2952.20 fazendo a conversão para money fica 295220.00 que está errado. Nos de mais tipo, mostra a mensagem de erro que nvarchar não possível converter para tipo numérico.

Os métodos de conversão que usei no SQL:

```
CAST(ISNULL(VALOR,0) as MONEY) as VALOR

COVNERT(MONEY, ISNULL(VALOR,0)) as VALOR
```

Tem algum tipo de tratamento que preciso fazer para converter campo nvarchar para algum tipo numérico de forma correta?

Comment: O valor que está na tabela tem realmente um PONTO - 2952 **.** 20? Utilizando um `convert` com ponto, ele deveria funcionar normalmente, mas, se for uma VIRGULA, aí vai ficar errado como falou.

Comment: @Ismael Realmente foi falha minha em confundir o ponto com a virgula. Fiz o `replace` de vírgula por ponto funcionou normalmente.